# Select element based on text inside Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I scrapped a website and I want to find an element based on the text written in it. Let's say below is the sample code of the website:

```
code = bs4.BeautifulSoup("""<div>
<h1>Some information</h1>
<p>Spam</p>
<p>Some Information</p>
<p>More Spam</p>
</div>""")
```

I want some way to get a *p* element that has as a text value `Some Information`. How can I select an element like so?

Answer (score 0):

Just use `text` parameter:

```
code.find_all("p", text="Some Information")
```

If you need only the first element than use `find` instead of `find_all`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `text` to search all tags matching the string

```
import BeautifulSoup as bs
import re
code = bs.BeautifulSoup("""<div>
<h1>Some information</h1>
<p>Spam</p>
<p>Some Information</p>
<p>More Spam</p>
</div>""")


for elem in code(text='Some Information'):
    print elem.parent
```